# Casting date stored as varchar as timestamp error

Tags: sql, parameters, casting, timestamp, varchar

I have a date stored as VARCHAR(10). I want to select as a timestamp

```
 SELECT     CAST (date AS TIMESTAMP)     AS created_timestamp
 FROM     dates;
```

I get:

```
 Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'CAST': SELECT CAST (date AS TIMESTAMP) AS created_timestamp FROM dates
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) What does the data look like?  (3) Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast to a timestamp in MySQL. There is a function called `TIMESTAMP` that will do it for you though.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(date) AS created_timestamp FROM dates;
```

Comment: If the OP is using MySQL/Oracle, then you are grossly wrong in your answer. `TIMESTAMP` is a data type in MySQL and Oracle. [See this for MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) [And this for Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)

Comment: Sorry. I'm assuming MySQL, and you're right, `TIMESTAMP` is a type. I'll edit to say that it can't be used by `CAST` instead.

Comment: I now get this message: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 1 to TIMESTAMP.: SELECT TIMESTAMP(date) AS created_timestamp FROM dates

Comment: If you have dates that are all zero in the field then you will get this error. You can configure your connection to MySQL to give null instead of an error in these cases using `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`.

Comment: I get the following error message in SQL server: 'TIMESTAMP' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I assumed that you were using MySQL, because you never said what you were using. This won't work in general, and I don't know about SQL server I'm afraid.